# "LLVM ERROR: Symbol not found: __svml_cosf8_ha" while calculating mel spectrogram using Librosa

Tags: librosa

I am trying to calculate the mel-spectrogram of an audio file using Librosa, and it throws this error while calling the function

```
spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=data, sr=fs, n_fft=fft_length, win_length=window_length_samples, hop_length=hop_length_samples, fmin=self.args.mel_min_hz, fmax=self.args.mel_max_hz,power=1, n_mels=self.args.mel_bands, htk=False)
```

I tried reinstalling librosa and its dependencies, but to no avail. This worked on my previous machine with an Intel CPU, but I recently got a new one with an AMD cpu, and it would not work anymore.